# How To Share Files In Salesforce With More than 2000 Users

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits, sharing, files, apex-managed-sharing

We have a **Managed Package**, where three **documents are fetched from a third party via API** and saved in Salesforce.

Once the users are provided with the **access of this Managed Package**, we need to **share the documents with these users** as well(the access of these documents will be provided **by the apex components in the Managed Package**), so that they can use these documents for the **features and functionality of the Managed Package Application** in Salesforce.

**There is a limit of Salesforce for sharing the document to 2000 users only or we can share via creating Groups or Make a Public Link**(and these both cannot be done/permitted) and share with them. This is not possible because this needs to be done as a functionality of the Managed Package itself.

**Please suggest any way to achieve** this functionality through Managed Package, where we would be **sharing the Documents fetched via API in Salesforce**, **to be shared with the users in Salesforce and the user count can vary from 10000-40000 in Salesforce.**

Comment: Why can't you consider groups? By "public link" do you mean to all users who have authenticated to the org or do you mean literally a public link? Could you [edit] the question to provide a bit more explanation here?

Comment: We cannot consider Groups, because we do not know that the org installing the application have Groups implemented or would like to have it implemented. Also, the users who are outside a Group might also be give access.

Comment: That reason doesn't sound valid to me. Just because they are not using groups for other purposes doesn't prevent the managed package using some specific groups to perform functionality needed by that package.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with a simple [edit] to add more detail about what you have considered, why you have rejected these options (and whether the rejection is self-imposed or based on some specific guidance in the Salesforce documentation, for example), and to cover why you cannot use standard sharing functionality.

Comment: @PhilW, if we consider using "Groups" then does the 2000 Users limit come into Count? Like for example, if I add 20000 users to the group and share the file with the Group will Salesforce consider it as sharing with 20000 shares or just one because shared the file with the Group only?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382136&type=1) covering Public vs Personal groups. While I haven't found a specific, official article about group membership limits, my understanding is that public group membership numbers are unlimited (though you should have no more than 100000 groups on your org). Take a look at the various answers [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8B8PSAV) for some more on that.